# Cannot set property value to target type from sqldatareader type

Tags: c#

```
List<T> returnList = new List<T>();
conn.Open();
SqlCommand sCmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
SqlDataReader dataReader = sCmd.ExecuteReader();
T t = new T();
PropertyInfo[] p = o.GetType().GetProperties();
while(dataReader.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p[i].GetValue(t)+" "+p[i].PropertyType+" 
        "+dataReader[i].GetType());
        p[i].SetValue(dataReader[i], t);
    }
    returnList.Add(t);
}
return returnList;
```

I want to set the value of specific property at run time from sqldatareader  object.
But i am getting an exception of target type mismatch even though both references are of the same type

Comment: At which line to you get this exception ? How do you know that your columns in your datareader are in the same order than your properties ?

Comment: the line in which i'm setting the value and I've written a class the order in which my columns are placed in the table

Comment: Could you add in your code the method signature ? (public/private List<T> myMethodName...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here. The main one is that you make a wrong call to `SetValue()`.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291(v=vs.110).aspx):

> public void SetValue(object obj, object value)

So actually you are calling the method with the wrong placed arguments. Do this and it should be fine:

```
p[i].SetValue(t, dataReader[i]);
```

The second problem that you will encounter is that at the end your list will contain only the same object, because you create a new object only once (`T t = new T();`. To solve it, you must place this line inside your `while` loop.

Also, [use using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) for cleaner code and because you should dispose your command at the end... And close your connection.

All in all, this is the final code:

```
List<T> returnList = new List<T>();
conn.Open();
using (SqlCommand sCmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    SqlDataReader dataReader = sCmd.ExecuteReader();
    PropertyInfo[] p = o.GetType().GetProperties();
    while(dataReader.Read())
    {
        T t = new T();
        for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p[i].GetValue(t)+" "+p[i].PropertyType+" "+dataReader[i].GetType());
            p[i].SetValue(t, dataReader[i]);
        }
        returnList.Add(t);
    }
}
conn.Close();
return returnList;
```

Comment: Thanks that helped

Comment: @SohelAhmed If this answers your question, please mark it as the answer (the check mark next to the top of the answer). That way others will see that this question is answered.